# Latest SDK version 0.4.150414 giving never seen before warnings

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

What do these warnings mean when running our pipeline?

> 1497 [main] WARN  com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline  - Transform 
>   AsIterable2 does not have a stable unique name.  In the future, this
>   will prevent reloading streaming pipelines

Answer (score 1):

The warning in question indicates that the specified transform -- AsIterable2 -- isn't uniquely named. A likely cause of this is that there are two applications of an AsIterable transform at the top-level.

You can get rid of the warning by using the PTransform#setName method on the transform in question.

We attempt to infer names from the class names being applied. The only times it should be necessary to set an explicit name are:

1. When using an anonymous PTransform or DoFn.
2. When the same named transform is used multiple times within the same PTransform.

---

Specifically, requirement #2 means that if you use a named `PTransform` multiple times within an outer `PTransform` you need to make sure that each application has a different name. For instance:

```
input.apply(someTransform)
    .apply(View.<TableRow>asIterable().withName("iterable1"));
input.apply(someOtherTransform)
    .apply(View.<TableRow>asIterable().withName("iterable2"));
```

instead of:

```
View.AsIterable<TableRow> iterable = View.TableRow>asIterable().setName("aName");
input.apply(someTransform).apply(iterable);
input.apply(someOtherTransform).apply(iterable);
```

Comment: I tried setting the name, but the warning's still appear. Am I doing it right? "View.AsIterable<TableRow> iterable = View.<TableRow>asIterable();
  iterable.setName("aName");"

Comment: setName() returns void (at least in SDK version 0.4.150414), so the example won't even compile. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry about that. It should work if you replace the `setName` with `withName`.